# Unknown parameters in custom signal handler on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64

```
   0x0000000008001946:  mov    0xa8(%rdx),%rax
   0x000000000800194d:  lea    0x28(%rdx),%rsi
   0x0000000008001951:  lea    0x2(%rax),%rdi
   0x0000000008001955:  add    $0xe,%rax
   0x0000000008001959:  mov    %rax,0xa8(%rdx)
   0x0000000008001960:  jmpq   0x8001ee0
```

Above is the *full* disassembly of a signal handler which is customarily set by the program which I'm looking into, i.e., the program registers the signal handler and immediately invokes it by raising a `SIGILL` using the opcode `ud2`.

The signal handler is registered here:

```
   0x8001965:   push   %rbx
   0x8001966:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x8001968:   mov    $0x26,%ecx
   0x800196d:   sub    $0xa0,%rsp
   0x8001974:   lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
   0x8001979:   rep stos %eax,%es:(%rdi)
   0x800197b:   lea    -0x3c(%rip),%rax        # 0x8001946
   0x8001982:   lea    0x10(%rsp),%rdi
   0x8001987:   movl   $0x8000004,0x90(%rsp)
   0x8001992:   mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
   0x8001997:   callq  0x8000f60 <sigfillset@plt>
   0x800199c:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0x800199e:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x80019a0:   jne    0x80019bb
   0x80019a2:   lea    0x8(%rsp),%rbx
   0x80019a7:   xor    %edx,%edx
   0x80019a9:   mov    $0x4,%edi
   0x80019ae:   mov    %rbx,%rsi
   0x80019b1:   callq  0x8000f90 <sigaction@plt>
```

Where `0x8001946` is the address of the handler, as disassembled prior to that in the first code-block.

My question is regarding the first instruction of the signal handler which appears to make no sense at all, and I can't debug it since I can't put a breakpoint on it:

```
0x0000000008001946:  mov    0xa8(%rdx),%rax
```

`%rdx` is defined by the ABI as the third parameter passed to a function, and as defined by `sigaction` the third argument of `sa_sigaction` is a `void *` (a casted `ucontext_t` structure) but there is no `0xa8`th index into the definition of a `struct ucontext_t`, which leads me to believe it's something else.

I thought it might be an `%rdx` set before the `ud2` instruction is called:

```
   0x0000000008000fde:  test   %al,%al
   0x0000000008000fe0:  mov    $0x2,%edx
   0x0000000008000fe5:  je     0x8001028
   0x0000000008000fe7:  movslq %ebx,%rdi
   0x0000000008000fea:  mov    %rbp,%rsi
   0x0000000008000fed:  callq  0x8001190
```

But prior to the call to `0x80001190` (the bug), `%rdx` only contains `$0x2`. So I'm even more confused.

Could anyone shed some light on what `%rdx` could contain at `0x8001946` after a `SIGILL` is raised, and  the signal is passed off to the custom handler defined at that address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be `%rip` (the address of the `ud2`):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *context) {
    ucontext_t *uc = (ucontext_t*)context;
    printf("%llx\n", uc->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
}
```

compiles to:

```
handler(int, siginfo_t*, void*):
        movq    168(%rdx), %rsi
        movl    $.L.str, %edi
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        jmp     printf
.L.str:
        .asciz  "%llx\n"
```

(https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/RC064L)